# Export Mapbox-GL to video

Tags: mapbox, video-encoding, mapbox-gl

I want to create user generated maps and paths and export them to video. 
On this page, https://uber.github.io/kepler.gl/#/demo/ukcommute, I see that they export to a photo. Is it possible to create a video from a mapboxGL map?